# Download content for cells only for visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage

I have `UICollectionViewCell` with dynamic content download (image download). I have download in block in cell:

```
-(MainVCCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MainVCCell";

    MainVCCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Person *person = [self.fetchedResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.login setText:person.login];

    if(person.avatar) {
        [cell.avatarImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:person.avatar]];
    } else {
        [cell.avatarImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
        [AsyncUrl request:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some SSL URL",person.login] completeBlock:^(NSData *data) {
            dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Download queue", NULL);
            dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    MainVCCell *cellToUpdate = (MainVCCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    if(cellToUpdate) {
                        [cellToUpdate.avatarImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                    }
                    person.avatar = data;
                    [[CoreDataController sharedInstance] saveContext];
                });
            });
        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

And it work fine, but of course when i scroll several times, i get so many connections and download fire that some of them even timeout. I understand why is this happening. Is there a way to cancel connections in invisible cell blocks? I want to download only a visible content.

I'm familiar with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) but this library is not support SSL connections, so i can't use it.

Comment: Do you mean that the certificate is invalid and you need to work around that? But that you don't want to edit SDWebImage code?

Comment: I don't want to use it 3-party for it because SDWebImage solved one problem and creating much bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

Collection views have a delegate method that is called when the cell disappears

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Just make sure you have a method for stop the connection, then call that method.

[UICollectionViewDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView%3adidEndDisplayingCell%3aforItemAtIndexPath%3a)

Comment: I am more accustomed to the NSURLConnection rather than the GDC, so i can't really provide example code.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use delegate to download image to cells? Where to set a delegate for it?

Comment: Under cell for item at index path method, you call a method in the cell for [download Image] which does all the download actions

Comment: So the download should be in the cell subclass? And to it attach the delegate. This is serious MVC violation

Answer (score 0):

I strong recommend you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Then you create an array of `NSOperation` in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.operationQueue = [[NSMultableArray alloc]init];
```

In your `-(MainVCCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, make something similar to this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:posterURLRequest];      
operation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) 
    {
        if(cellToUpdate) {
          [cellToUpdate.avatarImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
        }
        person.avatar = data;
        [[CoreDataController sharedInstance] saveContext];             
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
      // manage errors
    }];
    [self.operationQueue addObject:operation];
    [operation start];
```

Them At `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
[self.operationQueue[indexPath.row] cancel];
```

Comment: I've just check out official docs: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/ and don't see `AFImageRequestOperation` class.

Comment: Just edited my answer, they changed AFImageRequestOperation To a normal AFHTTPRequestOperation with AFImageResponseSerializer. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1434

Comment: Yep, i read a docs, but this approach does not support SSL basic authentication, and there was a problem with blocks.

Comment: AFNetworking does support SSL with basic authentication, and which problem with blocks are you talking about?

Comment: Of course you should do little research about using SSL and basic authentication with AFNetworking.

Comment: Is this working? I have a UicollectionView with 100 elements and when i scroll down i want to prioritize the download of Images for the cells that are visible

Comment: Gabriel, I didn't test the code. But it should work. Give a try and then tell me ;)

Answer (score -2):

use NSURLConnection to start a download.

Create a subClass of NSObject which has one NSUrlConnection instance property , for this subclass you provide a link and it will download the image using NSUrlConnection.
Create instances of this class when ever you want to download an image and push it into an array ( say **ConnectionsArray**).

When you think, you dont want to download particular indexPaths images, just cancel those by using ConnectionsArray.
Get that particular download-instance using indexPath and ConnectionsArray,and call cancel method of NSURLConnection of that object.

NSURLConnection  has cancel method, which cancels the ongoing operation.